# What's the importance of a relationship with Gibbs state in the context of VarQITE or variational algorithms?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, vqe

Trying to figure out VarQITE or variational algorithm, I ran into the Gibbs state.
What's the importance of a relationship with Gibbs state in this context.  Why can we just use the arbitrary state and evolve it trusting the nature of variational nature?

Thanks